# Align X-Axis label on a straight line in Highcharts Column Chart

Tags: highcharts

My highchart's x-axis label will look something like this[image]

Is there any way to align those x-axis labels on a straight line?.

Code for X-Axis;

```
  xAxis: {
    categories: [2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2022,2023,2024,2025,2026,2027,2028,2029,2030,2031,2032,2033,2034,2035,2036,2037,2038,2039,2040,2041,2042,2043,2044,2045,2046,2047,2048,2049,2050,2051,2052,2053,2054,2055,2056,2057,2058,2059,2060],

        title: {
            text: 'Year'
        },
        labels: {
            step: 5
        },
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

check wheather staggerLines property is set to any number, if yes remove that . It will be under xAxis like below

```
     xAxis: {
        labels: {
                staggerLines: 2 //remove this
                 }
             }
```

Comment: @BKM Setting staggerline :null will level them but if label increases morr than chart area they will be tilted